# Large numbers in real world

Tags: big-list, applications, big-numbers

I am a high school math teacher and I am looking for a comprehensive list of large numbers which occur in real world.

For example

- There are $10^{14}$ cells in the human body
- $10^{100}$ is called googol and the name [google](http://www.google.com) is derived from this...
- There are $6\cdot 10^{23}$ atoms/molecules in one mole

So is there any good book or website (even better) where such examples are collected?

Comment: There are a couple of additional examples in Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_numbers#Large_numbers_in_the_everyday_world

Comment: Look at these slides by Terence Tao. They are terrific!  http://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/cosmic-distance-ladder.pdf

Comment: I have an uncountable amount of papers sitting on my desk. I say uncountable because anything finite or countable can be well-ordered and nothing about my desk points well-orderability, if anything I suppose it proves the axiom of choice is false. I saw several mathematicians (mostly set theorists, actually) whose office is in a much worse condition too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Lure of the Integers](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/knowledge/isbn/item1176050/?site_locale=en_GB), by Joe Roberts. [The Penguin Dictionary of Curious and Interesting Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Penguin_Dictionary_of_Curious_and_Interesting_Numbers), by David Wells. [Les nombres remarquables](http://blogs.ethz.ch/kowalski/2009/03/28/les-nombres-remarquables/), by le Lionnais.

EDIT: Here's a [website](http://mrob.com/pub/math/largenum.html) about large numbers (though mostly it's about numbers of interest only to mathematicians).

MORE EDIT: You'll find a few at [this website](https://sites.google.com/site/largenumbers/home/2-1/everydaylargenumbersforamodernworld), and there are links there which may lead to more.